# Laravel Binding Service Provider Concept

Tags: php, laravel, oop

Im currently learning how laravel framework builded and came to service provider section. in *class* **DatabaseServiceProvider** which extends **ServiceProvider** class i see this line of code :

```
$this->app->singleton('db.factory', function ($app) 
 {
    return new ConnectionFactory($app);
});
```

im confuse what is *app* in $this->app, whether *app* is an object from application class instance and if it does when it is instantiated so it can be used from *DatabaseServiceProvider* class since i dont see its instantiation process. thnks before for answering this newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel, the *app* variable is a service container. Think of it like a heart of the framework. Everything you use from Facades to DB connections is stored in there.

Moreover, you can store your own objects in the container by using the method you specified (`$this->app->singleton()`). There are actualy many more ways to interact with the container. The best way to research this is to look into Laravel's documentation ([Laravel Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container))

The *app* object is being instantiated on Laravel bootstrap so you can't see it in the service provider. Though I was curious enough to dig deep into the framework to find it. The class itself is located in `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` and is instantiated in `bootstrap/app.php`.

Comment: i guess that is what called as dependency injection sir? do the app object instantiated at runtime not when the class defined at the first time sir?

Comment: Class is instantiated in `bootstrap/app.php`, as I mentioned. Dependency injection is when you basically typehint a class into a method parameter like this `public function __consctruct(User $user)`. What Laravel does in the app container is that it _automatially resolves_ these dependencies. Read more here - [Larvel Routing - Explicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#explicit-binding)